# Spectra of two subalgebras of $C(X)$ where $X$ is an annulus

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-algebras

> Let $X=\{z \in \mathbb C:1\leq|z|\leq2\}\text{ and } f(z)=z,z\in X.$ Let $A$ be the smallest closed subalgebra of $C(X)$ generated by $1$ and $f,$ and $B$ be the smallest closed subalgebra of $C(X)$ generated by $f$ and $\frac 1f.$  Determine the spectra $\sigma_A(f)$ and $\sigma_B(f).$ What happens if $X$ is a circle?

**My attempt:** Clearly, $\sigma_{C(X)}(f)=X$ and $A\subseteq B \subseteq C(X).$ So $X \subseteq \sigma_B(f)\subseteq \sigma_A(f).$

Now, $A=\{p(f):p\text{ is a polynomial}\}.$ Therefore, $\dfrac{1}{\lambda-f}\not \in A$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb C.$ So, $\lambda-f$ is not invertible in $A$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb C.$ This implies $\sigma_A(f)=\mathbb C.$

Similarly $B$ is the set of all polynomials in $f$ and $\frac 1f.$ Therefore, $\dfrac{1}{\lambda-f} \in B$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb C\setminus X.$ So, $\lambda-f$ is not invertible in $B$ if and only if $\lambda \in X.$ This implies $\sigma_B(f)=X.$

**My questions:** $1.$ Is the above solution correct? $2.$ What happens if $X$ is a circle. I don't see how anything would change.

**Note:** This question has previously been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265034/let-k-be-a-circle-describe-the-spectra-of-two-subalgebras-of-ck) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753770/rudin-functional-analysis-chapter-10-exercise-13?rq=1) However, my question is not a duplicate since it shows my attempt and I want to know if my solution is correct.

Comment: Well, $\sigma_A(f)=\mathbb C$ can't be right - we know that $\sigma(x)$ is compact for any element of any Banach algebra. It's not true that $A=\{p(f)\}$, because that set is not _closed_.

Comment: Hint: If $p_n\to g$ uniformly on $X$ then $p_n-p_m\to0$ uniformly on $X$, and so the Maximum Modulus Theorem shows that in fact $p_n-p_m\to0$ uniformly on $Y$, where $Y=\dots$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So, $A=\overline{\{p(f)\}}?$ So for $\frac{1}{\lambda-f} \not \in A$ if $\lambda \in X?$ To answer your question $Y=\overline{X}?$

Comment: No, $Y$ is much larger than $\overline X=X$. Ok, I'll tell you: $Y$ is the closed unit disk.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Is it correct that $\sigma_A(f)=X?$

Comment: No, $\sigma_A(f)\ne X$. It's true that $\sigma_B(f)=X$, but your explanation is wrong. First, $B$ is not what you say it is. Second, $1/(\lambda - f)$ is not a polynomial in $f$ and $1/f$. Finally, it doesn't really make any sense: You say (incorrectly) that $1/(\lambda-f)\in B$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb C$. If that _were_ true it would say $\sigma_B(f)=\emptyset$. Your "proof" that $\sigma_B(f)=X$ has nothing to do with $X$, so it can't be right.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Actually, I say that $1/(\lambda-f) \in B$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus X.$

Comment: Fine. But read the rest of what I wrote: What does "$1/(\lambda-f)$ is a polynomial in $f$ and $1/f$" have to do with $X$? The statement doesn't mention $X$ - if it were true for all $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus X$ it would have to be also true for all $\lambda\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: If $\lambda \in X,$ then $\lambda -f$ vanishes at $\lambda.$ So $1/(\lambda-f) \not \in C(X).$ I understood your point that $1/(\lambda-f)$ is not a polynomial in $f$ and $1/f.$

Comment: That last comment is correct. Yippee. What does it imply about $\sigma_A(f)$ and $\sigma_B(f)$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Won't $1/(\lambda-f)$ be limit of polynomial in $f$ and $1/f$ and hence in $B?$

Comment: If $\lambda\notin X$ and "limit" means "uniform limit on $X$" then yes. But you have to prove that...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes. But I'm still confused about $\sigma_A(f).$

Comment: $\sigma_A(f)$ is the closed unit disk. This has to do with the Maximum Modulus Theorem.

Comment: There'd be no change to $\sigma_B(f)$ if $X$ is a circle.

Comment: @Mark What about $\sigma_A(f)?$

Comment: @Mark So if $X$ is a circle $\sigma_B(f)$ is still an annulus? Heh: The meaning of "$X$" changes, but actually it's $\sigma_A(f)$ that doesn't  change; $\sigma_B(f)=X$ in both cases, so it _does_ change.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think Mark meant that $\sigma_B(f)$ would still be $X$(circle not annulus).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Since $X=\sigma_B(f) \subseteq \sigma_A(f),$ so how can $\sigma_A(f)$ be the closed unit disk?

Comment: @SahibaArora Huh? $X$ is a subset of the disk - what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In $X, |z| \geq 1$ while in closed unit disk $|z| \leq 1$.

Comment: @SahibaArora Sorry, I missed the $2$. Every time here I've said anything about the closed unit disk I should have said the closed disk $|z|\le2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh, now things make more sense.

Comment: do anyone please suggest me a way on how to get that uniform convergence in $B$ i.e. how to show there exist  sequence of polynomials in $f$ and $\frac{1}{f}$ which converges uniformly to $\frac{1}{\lambda-f}$ for $\lambda \in {K}^c$

Comment: also how can one show that $\{\lambda \in \mathbb C : |\lambda| \le 1\}$ is in $\sigma_{A}(f)$